# Github workflow queckout all brachnches of a Repo

Tags: github, github-actions

I need, to checkout all branches of a repo, with an github action, and save each branch an a diverent foler at the Githb actions-VM, to work with those files. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

[`actions/checkout` issue 329](https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/329) mentions that this will fetch all branches:

```yaml
steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2
  - run: git fetch --depth=1
```

From there, you will need [`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree), [applied for every branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46102211/6309), to complete the initial checkout.

Comment: I seems to just copy the main branch. I filter the branches with "grep -E "*" "
and when I print the List of all branches with git branch -r
it shows me 3 branches

Comment: @Timi21 Then you might need to specify the fetch refspec completely: `git fetch --depth=1 +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`